# How to locate an element without specifying its type in Watir?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, watir, watir-webdriver

How can I locate an element just by specifying the text property, whether its a link or a button or something else.

In jquery, we can write:

```
$('*').filter(function(){return $(this).text()=="some text";});
```

How can I achieve the same goal in Watir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not know element type, but you know it's attribute (in your case, text):

```
browser.element(:text => "some text")
```

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden: I think it works both with watir and watir-webdriver gems.